protect nginx with oauth2 proxy using github
I am trying to make a simple example of using oauth2 proxy to illustrate how it works
so i made this docker-compose.yaml file
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    
  oauth2-proxy:
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.2.1
    ports:
      - "4180:4180"
    environment:
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER=github
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID=
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET=
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET=
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:4180/oauth2/callback
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAMS=http://nginx:80
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:4180
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS=*
      - OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE=false
    volumes:
      - ./emails.txt:/etc/oauth2_proxy/emails.txt

but when i run this file, the nginx container working properly, but oauth2 proxy not.
when i am trying to access the  http:localhost:80 it works but when i am trying  http://localhost:4180 or http://localhost:4180/oauth2 it tell me the site can not be reached!
what i want is just when i am trying to enter my app which is nginx here, it make me do authentication with oauth2 proxy first and then allow or deny me to access the app
Note: i used nginx here as a simple example it can bu any app.

Use the command docker logs -fn 100 oauth2-proxy to check oauth2-proxy logs, if OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID is empty will cause your app startup to fail, maybe that's the reason why the site can not be reached.
And avoid using localhost, as recommended by RFC 8252.
